# Getting POI name out of google maps API

Tags: google-geocoding-api

Is there a simple way of retrieving the POI 'name' using the google maps API?
for example when searching for "" I'm getting this [json](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=I%20Amsterdam%20sign&language=en) result. which does not contain any 'name' of the found location.
On the other hand, when searching google maps with the same string it shows the location 'name'
[needed name in green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RimDV.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get more informations about a POI, you should use the Places API.
You can make a Place Details request using the place_id :

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=your_api_key&place_id=ChIJF-cA-O4JxkcR3tQQGf6ALVs
```

Check this [doc](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) for more details.

The result will include the name used by Google Maps.